# The next time ....if you bring/brought

Tags: grammar

> The next time you come over it might be nice if you brought something.

The statement is about a possible future event, but how can one 'brought' something in the future? Why should the past verb be used?

How about this way, what is the difference: the next time ....if you bring something?

Comment: Are you sure I think the sentence lacks a **be**? I cant understand the sentence. If you add the source, it will become great

Comment: That's just the way subjunctive works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *past tense veb form* does not always refer to *past time*. The present tense verb form does not always refer to *present time*. There is no future tense in English, so both *past tense verb forms* and *present tense verb forms* are used to talk about future time. The *past tense* form here indicates doubt on the part of the speaker: he is not sure if "you" will ever bring something over. By contrast, using present-tense *bring* indicates that the speaker thinks that there is a possibility that you will bring something.

The same can be said of *come*. It is present tense verb form but talking about future time (*the next time*). It is *come* because the speaker thinks "your" coming over is a real possibility. The use of *came*, on the other hand (*the next time you came over*), would indicate that the speaker has some doubt that "you" will ever actually come over again.

If the speaker wants to express doubt about both events, he could use both *came* and *brought*. This would be a common thing to say. Last, if the speaker used *came* and *bring*, he is expressing doubt about the first event, but not expressing doubt about the second event. This last combination would be unusual, because if the speaker doubts you will ever come over again, he is probably not going to talk about you bringing something over as an actual possibility.

Comment: Thank you. Alan. I had a doubt that I would see a clear answer for this kind of question, but you made it so clear. Thank you.

Comment: Then, If I say "if you could come, I would let you know", does this express possibilty and possibilty? At the same time  "if you can come, I would let you know" means I highly expect you to come, but I am less sure about giving you the information, is that it?

Comment: Couldn't edit: not possibility and possibility, but doubt and doubt referring to my first line in the above comment.

Comment: @JoeKim Now you're using modal auxiliaries (could, can, would) and these can mean a lot of things besides just possibility/doubt. They can also express ability, eukkubgw, permission,... so it's not possible to give an answer in a comment. There is a tag on this site for modals, and there have been many questions asked about them.